# Putting the children of a section into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm a bit stuck here, I'm still new to code and hope this kind of question isn't too simple, but I was trying to figure out how to get multiple element IDs or data into an array.

```
<section id="bottomBox" class="j-characters">
     <div><img data-jval="a" id="jval-a" src="./images/1.png" class="j-char-img"/></div>
     <div><img data-jval="i" id="jval-b" src="./images/2.png" class="j-char-img"/></div>
</section>
```

So in the section there's about 40 div's with an image as it's child, I'm trying to put all those div's in an array, would there be a method to use the section ID and then have the children put into an array?   Or would it just have to be done with multiple div IDs.

(If this question isn't formatted properly or needs more information let me know!)

Comment: `"I'm trying to put all those div's in an array"` is a simple `document.querySelector(".j-characters").children` (the parent is "j-characters"). `"would there be a method to use the section ID and then have the children put into an array"` if you do what i did, then you can use `document.querySelector(".j-characters").getElementById("the-id-goes-here");`. I don't know if this is what you are wanting, the question seems unclear

Comment: So the end goal is to randomize the DIV's in the j-characters section, my idea was to get them into an array and use something like Math.floor and Math.Random to have them initialize in a random order.  I think the document.querySelector().children was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example for `push`ing three different elements data to three different arrays:

```js
// Create the arrays
let outputTag = []; // array to hold the elements (tag)
let outputId = []; // array to hold the elements id
let outputSrc = []; // array to hold the src attribute of the elements

// Get the images(elements)
let bottomBox = document.querySelectorAll('#bottomBox div img');

// Loop through all the images (elements)
for(let i = 0; i < bottomBox.length; i++){
  // Push the images(elements) to the the arrays
  outputTag.push(bottomBox[i]); // push the elements
  outputId.push(bottomBox[i].id); // push the elements id
  outputSrc.push(bottomBox[i].getAttribute('src')); // push the elements src attribute
}

// Print the arrays
console.log(outputTag);
console.log(outputId);
console.log(outputSrc);
```

```html
<section id="bottomBox" class="j-characters">
     <div><img data-jval="a" id="jval-a" src="./images/1.png" class="j-char-img"/></div>
     <div><img data-jval="b" id="jval-b" src="./images/2.png" class="j-char-img"/></div>
     <div><img data-jval="c" id="jval-c" src="./images/3.png" class="j-char-img"/></div>
     <div><img data-jval="d" id="jval-d" src="./images/4.png" class="j-char-img"/></div>
     <div><img data-jval="e" id="jval-e" src="./images/5.png" class="j-char-img"/></div>
</section>
```

You can even go further by creating an array of objects:

```js
// Create the array of objects
let outputObjects = []; // array to hold the elements

// Get the images(elements)
let bottomBox = document.querySelectorAll('#bottomBox div img');

// Loop through all the images (elements)
for(let i = 0; i < bottomBox.length; i++){
  // Push the images(elements) to the the array of objects
  outputObjects.push({number: i+1, id:bottomBox[i].id, src:bottomBox[i].getAttribute('src')}); // push the elements id
}

// Print the array
console.log(outputObjects);
```

```html
<section id="bottomBox" class="j-characters">
     <div><img data-jval="a" id="jval-a" src="./images/1.png" class="j-char-img"/></div>
     <div><img data-jval="b" id="jval-b" src="./images/2.png" class="j-char-img"/></div>
     <div><img data-jval="c" id="jval-c" src="./images/3.png" class="j-char-img"/></div>
     <div><img data-jval="d" id="jval-d" src="./images/4.png" class="j-char-img"/></div>
     <div><img data-jval="e" id="jval-e" src="./images/5.png" class="j-char-img"/></div>
</section>
```